# Access a view from another Cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to access a view element from another application in OS X? For example there are two apps and one has an `NSTextView`. It is technically possible that the second app can read the text from the first app's text view?

A similar case in Windows when you call `GetWindowTextA()` for a window which is not in your application.

Comment: Two apps running in separate processes, not two windows in the same app, right?

Comment: Yes, 2 different apps, implicitly different processes

Comment: Added an example to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and bind the textView's value to the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) standard defaults in app 1.

And in app 2, read the entry.  Have a look at [Preferences Utilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html) in how to read another apps preference.

Here is a quick example that gets the download path from Safari.

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
     CFStringRef  theValue;
    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    //-- THE PREFERENCE FOR ANOTHER APP
    CFStringRef appID =CFSTR("com.apple.Safari");

      //-- THE PREFERENCE KEY FOR ANOTHER APP:| GETS THE DOWNLOAD FOLDER PATH
    CFStringRef theKey  = CFSTR("DownloadsPath");


    Boolean didSynch;


    //-- TRY AND MAKE SURE THE OTHER APP SYNCHRONISES ITS PREFENCES;
    //--Writes to permanent storage all pending changes to the preference data for the application, and reads the latest preference data from permanent storage
    didSynch = CFPreferencesAppSynchronize (
                                         appID
                                         );
    if (didSynch) {
        //-- CALL METHOD TO READ THE PREFERENCE KEY VALUE
        [self readPrefValue :theKey : appID];

        NSLog(@"theValue %@",theValue);
    }



    CFRelease(theValue);
    CFRelease(appID);
    CFRelease(theKey);
}

    - (void)readPrefValue :(CFStringRef) Key : (CFStringRef) appID
    {
       theValue = CFPreferencesCopyValue (
                                           Key,
                                           appID,
                                           kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
                                           kCFPreferencesAnyHost
                                           );
    }



    @end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible (with public APIs).

You might have a remote chance controlling another app using [accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXOverview/cocoaAXOverview.html), but no such thing as directly accessing the `NSTextField` of another app in another process.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it too see how it works.